# Fedora 23 beta guest won't install VBox Guest Xorg drivers because X server version is a prerelease

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, drivers, virtualbox

I have tried everything I can think of. I've tried RPM Fusion, I've tried using the ISO, but both don't work. I have tried changing the stuff in the .run file, but the md5sum fails. I have tried removing the md5sum check entirely in the .run file. Didn't work. Can someone help me out with correctly installing the guest additions in Fedora 23 Beta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, it's now fixed now to work with new Xorg in VirtualBox v5.0.16. Just tried it out and Fedora 23 works like a charm:

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14797

Answer (score 0):

I have Fedora 23 (non beta) as a virtualbox guest and had the same problem and did this:

```
sudo dnf --showduplicates --allowerasing --releasever=22 downgrade xorg-x11-server-Xorg
```

And then I reinstalled the guest additions and all was good, fedora guest runs full screen resolution.
I have found the above solution here: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=306857.
It is basically a downgrade of X-Server.

Comment: I deleted my Fedora VM, but I'll keep that in mind